# Illegitimate screenshots?

Tags: security, screenshot

Our bank requires us to run Trusteer Rapport: http://www.bbt.com/bbtdotcom/business/online-services/online-banking/trusteer-rapport-online-fraud-protection-software.page

On two different computers, it has reported screenshots. On one computer, it reported msoutlook.exe was trying to take a screenshot. On another, it reported that msaccess.exe, internetexplorer.exe, explorer.exe were all trying to take screenshots. What is going on with this? Big brother? Is this even possible? or are these just false positives?

Comment: All of those sounds like false positives.  It sounds like you should get get a better bank that doesn't force you to run broken software.

Comment: I know it does. The problem is BB&T is HUGE! And very secure with everything they do. We literally can't pay our employees through their system without this software. And I have a really hard time believing that MS would do this. The odd thing is it's only ms software

Comment: So report the false positives and move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. All the MS Office products have a feature that allow you to insert screenshots, screen clippings, etc. directly from within the application. It would be a shared library function. That said, it's not unreasonable to think that malware might be exploiting this function, but I'm sure there are better ways to go about it. https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Insert-a-screenshot-or-screen-clipping-6d7e6041-140c-4476-8432-ebeaee8a44e6

Are you sure this isn't a legitimate use case? The person at that station might actually be using that feature.

If you're concerned with screenshots being taken, you can simply disable print screens via GPO for anyone that's not an admin.